# how to match datetime[ns] and datetime[D]

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, unicode

I use pandas to read a date list which ranges from 1982 to 2015 including weekdays only, which is type datetime[ns]. I want to separate the big list into small lists which is grouped by one year. What I do is the following:

```
list_Date = []
list_Close = []
for i in range(1982,2016):
    dateONEyear = []
    CloseOneyear = []
    date = np.arange(str(i),str(i+1),dtype='datetime64[D]')
    for ii,jj in zip(AAPL['Date'],AAPL['Close']):
        if str(ii) in date:
            dateBYyear.append(ii)
            CloseOneyear.append(jj)
    list_Date.append(dateONEyear)
    list_Close.append(CloseOneyear)
```

But it does not work. My question is:

1) How do I match those two different data type?

2) Or any one has better idea to group the data by the unit of ONE year?

3) I can use another method to read the date list, but the type is unicode, how can I match unicode to datetime64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list and dictionary comprehension to generate a dictionary keyed off of the year.

```
dates = pd.date_range('1982-1-1', '2016-1-28', freq='B')
date_dict = {yr: [d for d in dates if d.year == yr] 
                 for yr in range(dates[0].year, dates[-1].year + 1)}

>>> dates_dict[2016]
[Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-04 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-06 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-07 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-08 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-11 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-12 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-13 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-14 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-15 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-18 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-19 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-20 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-21 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-22 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-25 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-26 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-27 00:00:00', offset='B'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-28 00:00:00', offset='B')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very inspired. But I want to the dates in the format like this.1982-01-11
1982-01-08
1982-01-07
1982-01-06
1982-01-05
1982-01-04, dtype: datetime64[ns]. Holidays also excluded. Becuase I want to use the data and the price to make some plots.

Comment: To be clear, you'd like the result as formatted text (no longer a timestamp)? If so, just do this: ` {yr: [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for ...`

Comment: Sorry, I still want the dates to be dtype:datetime64. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `[d.to_datetime64() for d in dates...]`? Results in numpy.datetime64 types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I can figure it out now with your help.